# How to insert multiple values from one table to another?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Need a small help in creating an oracle query.

I have a table in which I want to insert data from another table.

I get the account numbers from this table by using query:

```
select AccountNumbers from Company;
```

It returns me,

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
5678
```

Now I want to insert this data in another table.

```
Insert into tempTable (id, group, accountNumber) values (seq_mytemp_sequence, 'A', (select AccountNumbers from Company) );
```

I have created the sequence which works fine. But it fails saying that the sub query returns more than one row which is obvious.

I want the data in temp table to be inserted in such way that that it will be like this,

```
1 A 1234
2 A 2345
3 A 3456
4 A 4567
5 A 5678
```

I tried using loop, but its difficult to fetch individual account as the rownum doesnt work for anything other than 1.

Can someone guide me about how to do this? Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be like:

```
Insert into tempTable (id, group, accountNumber) 
select seq_mytemp_sequence, 'A', AccountNumbers from Company ;
```

And not like:

```
Insert into tempTable (id, group, accountNumber) 
values (seq_mytemp_sequence, 'A', (select AccountNumbers from Company) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and when you want a number from a sequence you need `.NEXTVAL`:

```
INSERT INTO tempTable (id, "group", accountNumber)
SELECT SEQ_MYTEMP_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
       'A',
       AccountNumbers
FROM   Company
```

*(Also, please do not give columns names which are key words like `GROUP` as you will have to wrap them in double quotes and then Oracle will enforce case sensitivity on the column name)*

Answer (score 0):

Insert Into tablename (Productid, 'name', acountnumber)
Select ProductId,'ABC','XYZ' from Producttable